# Error while passing custom model into firestore using angular4, requires object

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have a custom model and getting an error (mentioned below) while adding to firebase collection.

Could someone please advise what is missing or what is that I am doing wrong ?
I want to pass the custom object while adding the data to collection.

```
**`ERROR FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom '' object`**


export class UserProfiles{
  userid?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;

}

 addItem(){
    var userProf = new  UserProfiles();
     userProf.userid = 'unique';
     userProf.firstName = 'first name';
    userProf.lastName = 'last name';

     this.itemsCollection.add(userProf);
  }

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<UserProfiles>;
  items: Observable<UserProfiles[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('UsersProfiles');
}
```

one closing brace missing

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('UsersProfiles');
```

correct it or edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread construction to add the object

```
this.itemsCollection.add({...userProf});
```

this is a better/easier syntax than naming all the properties.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add the data to collection using below approach

this.itemsCollection.add({'userid':'unique', 'firstName':'sample f name', 'lastName':'sample l name'});